# iOS Build failure for CodenameOne

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I've built the iOS version of my app about a month or so ago. Then added a few extra messages to the UI, tested with the Android version and now when I rebuild the iOS version it seems to fail.  The error log is at: https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/621a8710-2900-45a3-afdb-e3a30bdb1265-1504680431641-error.txt

At the bottom of this, the only actual failure I see is: 
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/arm64/com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocketNativeImplImpl.o MyApplication-src/com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocketNativeImplImpl.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Failed xcodebuild step
```

I have updated the CN1Libs a few days ago.  Not really sure what about this is actually failing to build.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the file `com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocketNativeImplImpl.m` is mentioned in the final lines which means that's the file that failed. If you search the file for mentions of `com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocketNativeImplImpl.m` you will find:

```
src/com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocketNativeImplImpl.m -o /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7085253492970683151xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/arm64/com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocketNativeImplImpl.o
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7085253492970683151xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocketNativeImplImpl.m:23:9: fatal error: 'com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocket.h' file not found
#import "com_codename1_io_websocket_WebSocket.h"
        ^
1 error generated.
```

This might be a bit confusing but it generally means you added the cn1lib for websockets and didn't use it. That's a problem as our VM strips out unused code but the websockets cn1lib needs to include the callback interface which is now stripped away.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  After reviewing my code based on your comment, I found that yes, I am no longer using the web socket lib, and I'll remove it.